# SSRS - Merge Cells of Same Data Vertically

Tags: excel, reporting-services

Please see attached screenshot as I think this will help show better.  I have an SSRS report, in that one column can have the same value across many rows.  For this report, you can see Site column has a value of "JAC-FL".  How can I "merge" this so it only appears once (See screen shot of "Excel Layout" as I know how to do this in Excel).  For the life of me, I cannot seem to get this.

I already have a rowgroup defined for the data (see Row Group screenshot) (Please note, there is data for Username, but I removed it so it wouldn't appear in the screen shot).

Site = lvl_2_value, UMFullName = User Name, stream_3_Stream = Stream

I cannot seem to get my Site (I plan on doing this to the other columns as well, but thought if I get the first to work, I can do it to the others) to appear like the Excel layout.  Would anyone be able to help?

[image: Row Group]

[image: Excel Layout]

[image: Screenshot of Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to split out the rows into child groups, instead of grouping on all of them at once. Take a look at the bottom left of your first screenshot, you can see the "row groups" section there.

If all you see in that box is a line that says "(Details)", then you will need to start by right-clicking that and adding a parent group. Then you can add a child to that parent, and so on, going from most inclusive to least inclusive. So for example, if we were working with locations, we could do something like Country > State/Province > City).

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkwUX.png)

It may be easiest to start a new tablix (keep your old tablix until you're done though so you can copy and paste expressions and get the formatting right again!), as things tend to get shifted around when you add groups to an existing tablix.